# installing older version of wine on Mavericks from tar.bz2 file

Tags: osx-mavericks, tar, macports, wine

After all the struggles I have gone through trying to successfully install this specific release of wine (1.5.8) I have given up and decided to turn to this forum for help. I remember that a program I desperately need to use stopped working after I updated wine. The last version I remember it worked perfectly on is the very version 1.5.8, which I have downloaded from here: http://www.winehq.org/announce/1.5.8  as a tar.bz2 file. I always installed and managed wine via macports but this time it will not be possible since macports doesn't allow me to install older versions of wine. I would like to ask you please if anyone could help me and tell me (explain) how to install this particular version of wine from that tar.bz2 file. I'm using OS X Mavericks. The program I'm trying to run is Lingea Lexicon 5 but it's not really important, I remember it worked perfectly on 1.5.8 but it doesn't on the current release 1.6.2, it crashes at start.
Thank you very much in advance and please bear in mind that I'm not an experienced user of Terminal, I can do some basic things but my knowledge of commands is limited.
Thank you again.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

How about just install the old version of the port;

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort

Comment: thank you eborisch for your advice but that would work only if I had installed that version previously and had updated to a newer version, which is not my case. I have not installed any version of wine but I want to install the 1.5.8 version. According to the steps on the page you provided I was not able to get it to work and I have tried everything that was described in the link. How about any way to compile from that tar.bz2 archive I have downloaded?